# What is wrong my code (trying to abbreviate)?

Tags: ruby, irb

I am using irb/ruby1.9.1.

#### 1st step

I wrote the code below:

```
  def isUppercase  
    self>= ?A && self<= ?Z  
  end  

 class String  
    def abbreviate  
      abbr = ""  
      each_byte do |c|  
        if c.isUppercase  
          abbr += c.chr  
        end  
      end  
      abbr  
    end  
  end
```

#### 2nd step

I am evaluating the code below which I expected to be "UFO".
`"Unidentified Flying Object".abbreviate`

However, errors occcured.
How do I correct it?
the error is here.

```
irb(main):044:0> load("abbrevi.rb")
=> true
irb(main):045:0> "Unidentified Flyng Object".abbreviate ArgumentError: comparison of Fixxnum with String failed
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/abbrevi.rb:4:in >=' from 
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/abbrevi.rb:4:in isUppercase' from 
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/abbrevi.rb:12:in block in abbreviate' from 
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/abbrevi.rb:11:in each_byte' from 
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/abbrevi.rb:11:in abbreviate' from (irb):45 from 
C:/Ruby192/bin/irb:12:in <main>
```

Comment: Usually, the error message tells you how to correct the error. Since you didn't provide the error message, there is nothing there to tell you.

Comment: @KotaroEzawa: don't put things like that in comments. Edit your question to add the details (I just did that for you this time). And please use the `{}` button to format code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Fixnum
  def isUppercase
    self.chr >= ?A && self.chr <= ?Z
    #note use of `chr` to avoid error that occurs when
    #comparing a Fixnum to a String
  end
end

class String
  def abbreviate
    abbr = ""
    each_byte do |c|
      if c.isUppercase
        abbr += c.chr.to_s #note this usage as well
      end
    end
    abbr
  end
end
```

Note that you cannot add a string to a number, or compare, so the below will generate errors:

```
irb> 1 >= "A"
# => ArgumentError: comparison of Fixnum with String failed
```

**UPDATE:** @coreyward's answer is the better way to do what you're doing overall, but my answer is only pointing out how to fix your code and the reason for you error. A yet better way might be to use Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why you're checking if a *byte* is uppercase, rather than a *character* (there are multi-byte characters), but this sidesteps your issue entirely:

```
class String
  def abbreviate
    each_char.reduce('') do |abbr, c|
      abbr += c if ('A'..'Z').include?(c)
      abbr
    end
  end
end
```

This still doesn't really take non A-Z letters/characters into account, though.